# Dimensions of ID3D11ShaderResourceView

Tags: c++, directx, shader, direct3d, directx-11

Is it possible to get the Dimensions of the image represented by a `ID3D11ShaderResourceView`?
I create a 2D texture using

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* m_texture;
D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(D3DDevice, filename, NULL, NULL, &m_texture, NULL);
```

Now I want the dimensions of the image represented by `m_texture`. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call GetResource(&resource) on the ID3D11ShaderResourceView it'll return you the underlying ID3D11Texture2D (after a cast). With that you can call GetDesc(&desc) and inspect the Width and Height members of D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC.

Comment: I assumed he was after Width/Height rather than the ViewDimension, but the initial question was ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ID3D11ShaderResourceView::GetDesc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. It fills the D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC structure which has the ViewDimension field.